# How to shift "arguments"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's the script:

```
function runScripts() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: arguments[0]
    }, function() {
        arguments.shift();
        runScripts.apply(null, arguments);
    });
}
```

It doesn't work because `arguments` is not actually an array, it's just array-like. So how can I "shift" it or hack off the first element so that I can apply this function recursively?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume you want to reference the *original* `arguments`, instead of that from the callback you're passing to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

If so, you'll need to cache it first.

```
function runScripts() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return;
    var args = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply( args, arguments );

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: args.shift();
    }, function() {
             // using the modified Array based on the original arguments object
        runScripts.apply(null, args);
    });
}
```

Comment: Eh...? Why would you assume that? Each iteration handles only the first element, and then it calls itself with the remainder until there are none left. I'm not really sure what your version is supposed to do.

Comment: Oh..nevermind. Because of the anonymous function... you're right then, except it's still not supposed to pass in the first element.. it's supposed to pass all but the first.

Comment: @Mark: You have 2 functions. Maybe I'm wrong, but I interpreted your question as wanting to pass on the `arguments` from `runScripts()` *into* the callback you're passing to `executeScript`.  It isn't an odd assumption to make since you're referencing `arguments[0]` *outside* the callback, then trying to `.shift()` *inside* the callback.

Comment: @Mark: I did a recent update. Right now it is doing a `.shift()` when it applies the first argument to `file:`. In the callback, `args` will be modified.

Comment: @patrick: Yes, now that makes more sense. Accepting this answer for catching the bug I didn't even know existed :D

Comment: You can also convert arguments to a real array using `var args = [].concat.apply([], arguments)`

Answer (score 36):

```
var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
params.shift();
```

You can check out this [blog post](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript) which explains it in further detail.

Comment: I stumbled across that blog post too, but if I run `alert(args.length)` it tells me 0, whereas `arguments.length` tells me 2. Something's amiss. **Edit:** Crap... I see. The anonymous function is screwing it up.

Comment: Here's a minor optimization that'll protect you from a modified `Array`: `[].slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: Why not just use `[].shift.call(arguments)`? ;)

Comment: or even better, `[].shift.call(arguments,1)` then you don't need the `.shift()`.

Answer (score 13):

`[].shift.call(arguments)` is also valid. I'm using this in production code and it works as expected.

With this approach, your function becomes a bit more succinct:

```
function executeScripts() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: [].shift.call(arguments)
    }, function() {
        executeScripts.apply(null, arguments);
    });
}
```

If you look on MDN, they state that `shift()` was implemented with this flexibility in mind.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Too bad they didn't just implement `arguments` as a real array to begin with. But you are right. In fact, all methods from `Array` can be used on *any* object, as long as that object has a `length` property. That's mandated by the language spec. The secret to this magic is that below the surface, arrays are just objects with numbers as the property keys.

Answer (score 6):

You can transform `arguments` into a regular array like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to point out a potential problem with **[].shift.call(arguments)**.

This seems to have the perhaps unclear intent of shifting your arguments - even for your function's **named** parameters - even if used prior to the shift statement.

For example,

```
function testShift (param1, param2) {
    [].shift.call(arguments); 
    if (param1=="ONE") alert("ONE");
}
```

If you make the following call, what might you expect to happen?

```
testShift("ONE", "TWO");
```

If you expected param1 to stay "ONE", your fix is to set a var to param1 before the shift occurs. It looks like javascript is not binding param1 until the line it is called on - not when the function is called... so modifications to arguments prior to a parameter being used can have unexpected effects.

Hopefully now, you'll be able to expect it.

Comment: TIL. That's quite unexpected behaviour. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 you can now use Array.from() [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

e.g.

```
const args = Array.from(arguments);
const str = args.shift();
```

Comment: In ES6 you can also use variadic args: `function f(...args) { args.shift(); }`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to convert it to an array and then shift. Or, alternatively, drop the first item when converting to an array. `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` would work for this.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of JS, we can now write:

```
function f(first, ...rest) { ... }
```

Or

```
function f() {
    const [first, ...rest] = arguments;
}
```

Which is a little nicer than "shifting" off the first arg. However, if we did want to, we could first convert `arguments` into a proper array via `Array.from` or `[...arguments]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article explains this really well.  I copied some key points below.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arrayprototypeslice.shtml

For array, remember you can call the slice function to get a sub array.

```
var abc = [1,2,3,4,5];
abc.slice(0); //[1,2,3,4,5]
abc.slice(1,3); //[2,3]
```

Since the argument object is only array like, not really an array.  The call() / apply() function basically just "borrow"  the slice function from Array and use it on the Argument object, and you can even pass parameters into the slice function just as acting on the array.

```
var myobject ={ // array-like collection
    length: 4,
    '0': 'zero',
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
    '3': 'three'
}

var myarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(myobject) 
// returns myobject as a true array: ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]

var myarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(myobject, 1) 
// returns ["one", "two", "three"]
```

The one remaining question is why we're calling slice() on the prototype object of Array instead of an array instance. The reason is because this is the most direct route to accessing the slice() method of Array when that's all we're interested in; we could have first created an array instance, but that's less efficient and arguably more abstruse:

```
var myarray = new Array().prototype.slice.call(myobject) // less efficient
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the arguments to an actual array and then use that array in the rest of your logic in the function.

```
function runScripts()
{
  var i=0, l=arguments.length, arr=[];
  while(i<l)
  {
    arr.push(arguments[i++]);
  }
...rest of your function code
```

Edit to add: i've had issues with `prototype` and `call` in older versions of IE, so it really depends on what support you'll need.

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to support IE :) Just Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
function executeScripts() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: args.shift()
    }, function() {
        executeScripts.apply(null, args);
    });
}
```

It's useful when writing Google Chrome Extensions. I wanted to use jQuery in my content script, but then you have to load it first. Turns out out by chaining calls to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` you can do this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    executeScripts('jquery-1.4.4.min.js', 'content.js');
});
```